# Call jquery datepicker viewhelper from custom viewhelper

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, viewhelper

I have a custom view helper in app/view/helper folder. The code for add text field is - in my code:
    $this->view->formText('date');
But instead of text field i want to add jquery datepicker like this:
    $this->view->datePicker('date');

But this does not work. Please help.
Regards

Comment: <yoda>More explanation you must provide.</yoda> Doesn't work in what way? Server side error/exception? Client-side error? Fails to produce a working datepicker popup? Lots of blanks to fill here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, you do not need a view helper for this.

On the client side, just attach the jQuery datapicker to your element. How you target that element with a client-side selector is dependent upon the DOM hooks you have available in your page/form, but as an example, assuming a form with id `myForm` and an input field with name `myDate` that you would like to function as a datepicker, you could simply use:

```
function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myForm input[name="myDate"]').datePicker({
            // datepicker options here
        });
    });
}(jQuery);
```

Of course, this presumes that jQuery is loaded when this runs and that the datepicker plugin is loaded by the time the ready event fires on the document object.